# change uitabbar icons while view is already visible

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I was wondering if or how I could change my tabbar icons depending on which subview is currently visible on the main view.

Basically I have created this menu that allows the user to change the main(subview) what I would like to happen is check which main(suveiew) is currently visible then depending on which one is visible I would like to change the tabbar icons accordingly, However I am not sure how I could possibly do this.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this by attaching one view controller to each tab, then at any point in the view controller's code you can use the following code to change the tab's name:

```
self.title = @"New tab name";
```

Alternatively you can change the whole tab bar item, which will let you change the icon as well:

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"New tab name"
    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new_tab_image.png"]
    tag:YOUR_TAG
];
```

Comment: okay this sounds perfect..!! for now ill mark this answer as correct as it seems right.. thanks heaps.